# How are WLAN profiles stored on OSX/Windows/Android/iOS?

Tags: android, ios, windows, macos, wifi

Dunno if stackoverflow is the best place for this, but I'm wondering if there's any sort of uniformity to how information about 'known' WLANs is stored in different OSes and on different devices. Is it possible to query and get this information in a form that it can be used on other devices, for example?

Answer (score 0):

No, they're totally different operating systems with completely different APIs (although iOS and OS X are closely related).

Comment: Where can I find information on each system's way of interfacing with stored wifi profiles?